# Access VBA - Apply Filter - Multiple OR conditions cont

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was able to create this code from the question titled "Access VBA - Apply Filter-Multiple or Conditions". I am having a problem with the last 2 `Short_term_fix` and `Long_term_fix`. Each time I look for a value that I know is in these fields it does not find the record.

```
Private Sub Enter_Click()
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Issue Name] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & 
"*'" & _
" Or [Issue_Description] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [JIRA ID] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [Root_Cause] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [Short_term_fix] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [Long_term_fix] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'"

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the SQL you're building - adding ORs won't affect a query that is already finding results before the added filters. Add a line before that creates a string - and then Debug.Print that string. If it's a syntax error then check that the two new fields are 1. spelled correctly - and 2. text fields

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell by your example, but I believe you're coming across **the 255 character limitation of the WHERE clause for ApplyFilter**.

The best way to test this for truth is to use the Debug.Print method of a string variable that prebuilds your SQL statement before applying it.

With a quick test I was able to confirm that a 10 character search string should work - it results in a WHERE clause string with less than 224 characters.

It appears that the upper limit for search string length is 15 characters

You can test yourself by creating the variable and testing length before applying

```
Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "[Issue Name] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & 
"*'" & _
" Or [Issue_Description] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [JIRA ID] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [Root_Cause] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [Short_term_fix] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'" & _
" Or [Long_term_fix] like '*" & [Forms]![Q-Filter]![Text58] & "*'"

If Len(strSQL) > 255 then
   Msgbox "ApplyFilter string length exceeds 255 characters"
Else
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", strSQL
End If
```